# numberOfRowsInSection called too many time after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a function to open all section in a table view.

Very strange, when `[self.tvChoices reloadData];` was called, I got

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

To be called for EACH section (1300) and not only for the visibles.

Any idea?

(maybe I should just clean the tableview before reloadData, but i'm curious why this behaviour

```
-(IBAction)multipleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"--[%s:%d]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
    NSNumber *value=self.mybooleans[sender.view.tag];
    [self reset_Sections_BooleansTo:@(!value.boolValue)];
    [self.tvChoices reloadData];  <-- 
}
```

.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
```

-- called even for not visible section

Comment: Have you tried using UITableView.reloadSections(_:withRowAnimation:) instead?

Comment: I can try.  But what was not cool, is that i will have to manage witch section will need to be updated. (the action "open" the content of each section, so, when section are closed, I see only headers, when I open all section, probably only the first section will appear (the other doesn't need to be reloaded)

Comment: Are you sure it's calling 1300 not infinite loop? You can actually check that via debugger.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll take a look.  But doesn't make sense since in finally show the header and cell... and only the first section\6 first cell of the section was visible.  So why it can go thru a value of 1300 as section in numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I confirm that , even in viewdidload, callling  [self.tvChoices reloadData]; will make the tableview to call numberOfRowsInSection for each section (even the not visible).

The problem are that I have 2400 sections, it take time, too much time.

Any idea?  (based on this fact, do you think I should create a new stackoverflow question?)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior makes sense because the table view needs to estimate how big to make the scroll indicator. To do this, it needs to know how many total rows there are in the table view, thus it needs to ask how many rows are in each section.

If it is not a major performance hit for your app, just don't worry about it.  Worrying about how many times a method gets called and trying to reduce it for no significant performance gain is serious premature optimization and is rarely worth the work and bugs it causes.

If it is a performance hit, as some commenters have pointed out, you can look into `- reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `- reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` to only reload the rows/sections that need updating.